# How to store a buffer of single characters and print them out as a string?

Tags: c, buffer, translation

I posted a few questions about my project already and its all been helpful but I'm still unsure of one part of it.

I'm creating a translator that converts ASCII to ASH and ASH to ASCII. I have now successfully converted ASCII to ASH but can't convert from ASH to ASCII. I've created a function called 'ASCIIstring2ASHstring' which works fine, but I now have to create another function called 'ASHstring2ASCIIstring'. However, I've been told that for this function I need to save each character the user enters into a temporary buffer until a '/' appears, at which point I need to print out all the characters in the temporary buffer as a full string by calling the 'ASHstring2ASCIIstring' function (which I'm asking for help creating now) . However, I have no idea how I'd do this and I hoped someone here could lend me a hand :)

Thanks!

UPDATE: I have now created the function with some help, but for some reason its not printing out ASH to ASCII translations as expected, I have posted the updated code below.

```arduino
char ASH_a[] = "*";
char ASH_b[] = "!!*";
char ASH_c[] = "!!@";
char ASH_d[] = "*!";
char ASH_e[] = "!";
char ASH_f[] = "!*!";
char ASH_g[] = "**";
char ASH_h[] = "!**";
char ASH_i[] = "!!";
char ASH_j[] = "*!!";
char ASH_k[] = "*@";
char ASH_l[] = "!*@";
char ASH_m[] = "!*";
char ASH_n[] = "!@";
char ASH_o[] = "@*";
char ASH_p[] = "!@!";
char ASH_q[] = "*!@";
char ASH_r[] = "!@*";
char ASH_s[] = "@!";
char ASH_t[] = "@";
char ASH_u[] = "@@";
char ASH_v[] = "**!";
char ASH_w[] = "***";
char ASH_x[] = "*@!";
char ASH_y[] = "!@@";
char ASH_z[] = "**@";
//char ASH_1[] = "@!!*";
//char ASH_2[] = "@!!@";
//char ASH_3[] = "@!*!";
//char ASH_4[] = "@!**";
//char ASH_5[] = "@!*@";
//char ASH_6[] = "@!@!";
//char ASH_7[] = "@!@*";
//char ASH_8[] = "@!@@";
//char ASH_9[] = "@*!!";
//char ASH_0[] = "@!!!";
//char ASH_.[] = "@!!";
//char ASH_,[] = "@!*";
//char ASH_?[] = "@**";
//char ASH_![] = "@*@";
//char ASH_+[] = "@@!";
//char ASH_-[] = "@@*";
//char ASH_*[] = "@@@";
//char ASH_/[] = "@!@";


char t[] = "ash code";
char buffer1[100];
const int oblen = 100;
char ob [oblen];



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Serial.println(ASH2ASCII("!**")); //These are the ASH characters I want to convert to ASCII using the ASH2ASCII function
  //Serial.println(ASH2ASCII("!"));
  //Serial.println(ASH2ASCII("!*@"));
  //Serial.println(ASH2ASCII("!*@"));
  //Serial.println(ASH2ASCII("@*"));


  //ASCIIstring2ASHstring (t, ob, oblen);
  //Serial.println(ob);
  usinput(buffer1);
  Serial.print(buffer1);
  chardecide(buffer1);

}

void chardecide(char * buffer1) { //char decide which acts upon the result of isASH using the true and false returns
  if (isASH (buffer1)) {
    Serial.println(" has been recognized as ASH - ");
    ASHstring2ASCIIstring(buffer1, ob); //passes function with buffer1 and ob included
    Serial.println(ob); 
} else {
    Serial.println(" has been recognized as ASCII - ");
    ASCIIstring2ASHstring (buffer1, ob, oblen);
    Serial.println(ob);
  }
}

void usinput(char * ib ) {
  char inChar;
  int i = 0;
  do {
    while (!Serial.available()) {};
    inChar = Serial.read();
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      break;
    } else {
      ib[i] = inChar;
      i++;
    }
    ib[i] = '\0';
  } while (true);
}


bool isASH(char * buffer1)
{

  if (buffer1[0] != '*' && buffer1[0] != '!' && buffer1[0] != '@') return false;

  return true;

}

 int ASHstring2ASCIIstring(char *buffer, char *ob)  //converts ash to ascii
{
    char str[10];
    int j = 0;
    int l = 0;

    while (*buffer) {
        if (*buffer == '/') { //hit slash
            str[j] = '\0'; //empty buffer
            ob[l++] = ASH2ASCII(str);
            j = 0;
        } else {
            if (j + 1 < sizeof(str)) {
                str[j++] = *buffer;
            }
        }

        buffer++;
    }

    ob[l] = '\0';
    return l;
}

void ASCIIstring2ASHstring (char * ip, char * op, int oplen) { //converts ascii to ash

  op[0] = '\0';
  int bp = 0;
  int n;
  char m[9];
  int l = strlen(ip);
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    m[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(m, ASCII2ASH(ip[i]));
    n = strlen(m);
    if ((bp + n + l) < oplen) {
      strcat(op , m);
      bp = bp + n;
    }
    if (ip[i] != ' ' && ip[i + l] != ' ') {
      op[bp] = '/';
      bp++;
    }
    op[bp] = '\0';
  }
}


char ASH2ASCII(char * m) { //Using the char variables impmented globally, ASH2ASCII searches through specific variables until it finds a match for the conversion, at which point it will capture and reuturn the ASCII string

  if (strcmp(ASH_a, m) == 0) { //if string captured return a
    return 'a';
  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_b, m) == 0) { //else if b string is captured return
    return 'b';
  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_c, m) == 0) {
    return 'c';
  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_d, m) == 0) {
    return 'd';
  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_e, m) == 0) {
    return 'e';
  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_f, m) == 0) {
    return 'f';
  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_g, m) == 0) {
    return 'g';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_h, m) == 0) {
    return 'h';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_i, m) == 0) {
    return 'i';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_j, m) == 0) {
    return 'j';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_k, m) == 0) {
    return 'k';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_l, m) == 0) {
    return 'l';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_m, m) == 0) {
    return 'm';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_n, m) == 0) {
    return 'n';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_o, m) == 0) {
    return 'o';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_p, m) == 0) {
    return 'p';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_q, m) == 0) {
    return 'q';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_r, m) == 0) {
    return 'r';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_s, m) == 0) {
    return 's';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_t, m) == 0) {
    return 't';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_u, m) == 0) {
    return 'u';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_v, m) == 0) {
    return 'v';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_w, m) == 0) {
    return 'w';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_x, m) == 0) {
    return 'x';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_y, m) == 0) {
    return 'y';

  }
  else if (strcmp(ASH_z, m) == 0) {
    return 'z';

  }

}

void ASCIIstring2ASH (char * buf) {

  Serial.println(ASCII2ASH(*t));

}


char * ASCII2ASH (char c) { //This is the opposire of ASH2ASCII, it uses the globally defined variables to search through ASCII characters, and returns the ASH version of that character

  switch (c) {

    case 'a':
      return ASH_a;//returns ASH version of a if matched

    case 'b':
      return ASH_b;

    case 'c':
      return ASH_c;

    case 'd':
      return ASH_d;

    case 'e':
      return ASH_e;

    case 'f':
      return ASH_f;

    case 'g':
      return ASH_g;

    case 'h':
      return ASH_h;

    case 'i':
      return ASH_i;

    case 'j':
      return ASH_j;

    case 'k':
      return ASH_k;

    case 'l':
      return ASH_l;

    case 'm':
      return ASH_m;

    case 'n':
      return ASH_n;

    case 'o':
      return ASH_o;

    case 'p':
      return ASH_p;

    case 'q':
      return ASH_q;

    case 'r':
      return ASH_r;

    case 's':
      return ASH_s;

    case 't':
      return ASH_t;

    case 'u':
      return ASH_u;

    case 'v':
      return ASH_v;

    case 'w':
      return ASH_w;

    case 'x':
      return ASH_x;

    case 'y':
      return ASH_y;

    case 'z':
      return ASH_z;

    case ' ':
      return " ";

    default:
      Serial.println("switching went wrong!");
      break;

  }
}



void loop() {


}
```

Comment: You need to make ASH_x an array of 26 strings, rather than 26 separate variables.

Comment: You mean at the top of the program where I've defined all the char variables?

Comment: Yes, just consolidate all those separate strings into an array, then you can simplify the code by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Your approach is wrong for two reasons: **(1) You cannot try matching ASH codes in arbitrary order** - this would result in false positives. For example, you would never get a `g` or a `w`, because your code would interpret `g` as `aa` and `w` as `aaa`, and **(2) `strcmp` will not match in mid-string** - you would get zero only if both strings have the same length.

Comment: Haven't they taught you about arrays? Any time you have to type virtually the same thing 20 times, that should be a clue that there's a better way.

Comment: Your code organization is suboptimal, too - you can implement the same thing with loops replacing lengthy chains of `if`s, and arrays replacing the `switch`.

Comment: You guys make good points but that's just the way the project has been specified. Also, a / is placed after each character, so strings won't be wrongly interpreted as you suggested dasblinkenlight :), the main thing is that one part of the translation works for now, I just need help getting ash to ascii translation working, I'll work on cutting down the amount of code using arrays after that :)

Comment: Note that you've tagged this as `C`, but based on the use of `Serial.println` *et al* it appears to be the C/C++-based `Arduino` language ?

Comment: You're correct! I'm working on an arduino but didn't know how to tag it specifically so just tagged it as c overall to make the syntax easier for you guys to read, I understand it can cause confusions though :)

Answer (score 1):

In `<string.h>`, there is a function `strtok` that splits a string on a range of given characters. You could use it like this:

```
int ASHstring2ASCIIstring(char *buffer, char *ob)
{
    char *token;
    int l = 0;

    token = strtok(buffer, "/");
    while (token) {
        println(token);
        ob[l++] = ASH2ASCII(token);   // Note: No overflow check!
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
    ob[l] = '\0';
    return l;
}
```

On the first call, you supply the string to split, on subsequent calls you pass `NULL` to tell `strtok` to keep working on the same string. This code destroys the original string in the process, because it places end markers at the end of the tokens.

You can also code that behaviour yourself by filling an auxiliary buffer. When you hit a slash, process the buffer and empty it:

```
int ASHstring2ASCIIstring(char *buffer, char *ob)
{
    char str[10];
    int j = 0;
    int l = 0;

    while (*buffer) {
        if (*buffer == '/') {
            str[j] = '\0';
            ob[l++] = ASH2ASCII(str);
            j = 0;
        } else {
            if (j + 1 < sizeof(str)) {
                str[j++] = *buffer;
            }
        }

        buffer++;
    }

    ob[l] = '\0';
    return l;
}
```

This code leaves the string intact. It also requires that there is a slash after the last token. That may not be what you want, but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! That's a huge help, the only thing I don't understand is what is being used to print the final result? as with the ASCIIstring2ASHstring function I used ob to print when I called the function, and I declared ob globally.

Comment: These functions fill the string `ob` (without checking its bounds, so be careful). You can then print that string, just as you did with `ob` from the other function. You must, of course, pass `buffer1` and `ob` to the function.

Comment: I have called the function and printed it as follows, but its not working for some reason:              ASHstring2ASCIIstring(buffer1, ob);
 Serial.println(ob);

Comment: I have tested both variants before posting them, and both produce the desired output. (But I have converted the Arduino stuff to C.) Btw, what do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Does it crash? Does it print garbage? Doesn't it print anything?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post to include the updated code now. It doesn't print out anything, I'm sure I've called the function as you specified but don't seem to get any output, although I've called the ASCIIstring2ASHfunction in the same way and the output is fine. I just don't get the translation when I type ASH code into the serial port (as I'm currently running the program in the standard arduino editor).

Comment: My code looks similar. I'm not familiar with the Arduino stuff, but don't you need a prototype of `ASHstring2ASCIIstring` before you call it?

Comment: Yeah I have specified the function using : ASHstring2ASCIIstring(buffer1, ob);  
    Serial.println(ob);

Comment: You don't need a prototype before you call it, well I haven't done that with ASCIIstring2ASHstring,and it works fine

Comment: Well, in C that fact that something works doesn't necessarily mean that it's fine. All I can say is that the functions I provided work as intended. Your code doesn't return anything from `ASH2ASCII` and `ASCII2ASH` when there is no match. You could return a placeholder.

Comment: I found out the problem! I have to put a / after the string I want to translate. For example when I type in !/ it prints back 'e' in ASCII, which is correct. However, how would I change it so I can enter a string without having to put / at the end of it?

Comment: Oh, I has written that in my last paragraph. If you want to catch that case, check whether `l > 0` after the loop and if so, call `ASH2ASCII` again. In other words, put `if (j > 0) ob[l++] = ASH2ASCII(str);` directly after the while loop body.i.e. before you write the terimating null.

Comment: I have just done that be it still requires me to enter a / after each entered character or else nothing displays, that's fine though I'll just write a sentance telling the user to put a / after each entered ASH character, thanks for the help by the way! :)

Comment: When I do that in my code, it doesn't require a trailing slash. Even s, it shouldn't print nothing; it should print the string without the last character. There's maybe something else giong on.